# How to extract a DATETIME field only the TIME and convert it to INT in ssis (ssdt)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

i have to extract from a datetime field only the time and then convert it to int (like time key) in ssdt

i used this to extract the date:

`(DT_I4)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()),2))`

thanks

Comment: What is the desired output and format of the time you want?  You'll probably want to use DATEPART https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datepart-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sample data and desired results are essential here. There are LOTS of variations on presenting time as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that in TSQL, most probably it is the same in SSIS:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), GETDATE()) AS seconds
```